# Why does this C++ code not create a text file?

Tags: c++, output, text-files

I'm trying to get started making a random password generator in c++ that outputs to a text file. I used the c++ tutorial http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012

But the code doesn't open anything. Nothing happens when I run the program other than the console popping up and saying "press any key..."

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
srand(time(0));
char string1[8];
static const char alphanum[] =
    "0123456789"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) 
{
    string1[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
}

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example1.txt");
system("PAUSE");
myfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you look for a text file? I think with MSVC it will be in either the project directory or the solution directory (don't remember which)

Comment: I tried you code on Mac, it creates an empty file.

Comment: Does it not work if you run in debug mode? This is what it looks like when I run it on my windows 7. http://imgur.com/hMRVjrd

Comment: Post your exact code next time. I get a bunch of compile errors, you've obviously omitted some lines from before `_tmain` (whatever that is)

Comment: You are using C++ streams. I also suggest you use C++ strings. `string1` is not null-terminated in your code.

Comment: #include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include <fstream>using namespace std;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect this is creating a file it is just not likely where you expect it. Depending on how you are running the file it may not be where the exe is but wherever you working directory is set. If you want to really test run the exe from a shell or command prompt directly from in the directory in which it resides.

It is also worth noting that write to the file may not happen until after you close it. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/
When calling the close method this flushes outputs to the file. You should probably call this before your pause.

Comment: Okay, it turned out that it was doing what you said. It was creating the file where I didn't expect. I guess I was just confused because I thought it would open the file for my viewing when I ran the program. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Hi, can you please mark this as correct then so I get the points.

Answer (score 0):

The function `void open (const char* filename,ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);`. The default mode is `in|out`, but the file did not existed, so the `open()` excute fail. So you should use the `out` mode only for creating a new file, try `open("example1.txt", ios::out)`. The reason you can see here:

```
myfile.open("example1.txt");
if(! myfile.is_open())
    cout << "open failed" << endl;
myfile.close();
```

According to the codes above, you can get `open failed`. I hope this can help you.

Comment: He is using an `ofstream` which adds `ios_base::out` by default.

Comment: @BoPersson, he used `fstream` firstly, maybe edited it later.